# Who proved hexagonal tiling can only be three types?

Tags: geometry, reference-request

I know Reinhardt gave three types of hexagonal tiling, but he seemed not prove can only be three types.

I was told that it was proved in 1963, but I cannot find the reference.

Can someone give me hint?

Comment: In 1918, K. Reinhardt (Über die Zerlegung der Ebene in Polygone, Inaugural-Disstertation, Univ. Frankfurt a.M., R. Noske, Borna and Leipzig)

Comment: I know Reinhardt‘s work, but he didn't give the proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 1918, K. Reinhardt in his doctoral thesis at the University of Frankfurt showed that any tessellating convex hexagon belongs to one of three chlasses. Kershner, in the article "On Paving the Plane" (1969), explains the tree types.

[Reinhardt doctoral thesis](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN316479497)
A convex hexagon $P_6$ can tile the whole plane $\mathbb{E}^2$ if and only if it satisfies one of the three groups of conditions.

The if part of this theorem is relatively simple. However, the only if part
is much more complicated. Reinhardt deduced the only if part by considering six cases with respect to how many edges of the considered hexagon are equal. His proof was very sketchy and difficult to understand and check. It seems that he only considered the edgeto-edge tilings.
Fortunately, this theorem has been verified by several other authors. Without the knowledge of Reinhardt’s thesis, in 1963 Bollobás made the following observation, which guarantees the sufficiency of Reinhardt’s consideration.

> If $\mathcal{T}$ is a tiling of the plane by identical convex hexagons and $\gamma$ is any given positive number, there is a square of edge length $\gamma$ in which the tiling is edge-to-edge and every vertex is surrounded by three hexagons.

[Bollobás  - Filling the plane with congruent convex hexagons without overlapping](http://annalesm.elte.hu/annales06-1963/Annales_1963_T-VI.pdf) - Pg. 117

Reference

[On Paving the Plane](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.1968.11971075) 
[Mathematical Games - Martin Gardner](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24949848)
[Can You Pave the Plane Nicely with Identical Tiles](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.06610.pdf)